# Printing all permutations of integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, permutation

I've just written a code for printing all the possible permutations from *1 to n* in an int array in Java, but I think it is more complex than it needs to be. I am using Hashset to avoid repetitions. If someone finds something than can be simplified, please write.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProblemFour {
    private static int n;

    private static void printResult(int[] result) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        Integer[] nums = new Integer[result.length];

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            nums[i - 1] = result[i - 1];
        }

        for (Integer num : nums) {
            set.add(num);
        }
        if(set.size() == n) {
            String s = "[ ";
            for (Integer num : nums) {
                s += num + " ";
            }
            System.out.println(s + "] ");
        }
    }

    private static void permute(int[] result, int index) {
        if (index == result.length) {
            printResult(result);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result[index] = i;
            permute(result, index+1);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("From 1 to: ");
        n = input.nextInt();

        int[] result = new int[n];

        permute(result, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is meant for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is open-ended and therefore does not fit on this Q&A-site.

Answer (score 0):

I made this permutations code way back it uses lists as a data structure in it.

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] numbers) {
// we use a list of lists rather than a list of arrays 
// because lists support adding in the middle
// and track current length
List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
// Add an empty list so that the middle for loop runs
permutations.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
    // create a temporary container to hold the new permutations 
    // while we iterate over the old ones
    List<List<Integer>> current = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    for ( List<Integer> permutation : permutations ) {
        for ( int j = 0, n = permutation.size() + 1; j < n; j++ ) {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(permutation);
            temp.add(j, numbers[i]);
            current.add(temp);
        }
    }
    permutations = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(current);
}

return permutations;
```

}